# Rigged character renders in the original position, not in the pose I set

Tags: rendering, animation, rigging

I have downloaded a rigged character and I inserted my design in.
I can place my character in sit position, etc...
But when I start the render, my character appears in the original position, not in the sit position.

Can you help me to render in the position I want?

Comment: If you have keyframes on the armature it will appear according to it on render. Try to remove the action from the armature or delete all the keyframes or insert your own keyframes.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140059/bones-of-my-character-are-not-saving   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132448/how-can-i-prevent-my-posed-rigs-from-defaulting-back-to-the-static-stance-also   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61478/unable-to-render-pose-ive-rigged-my-mesh-changed-its-pose-and-now-it-does-n